# jQuery Cycle & Wordpress // Thumbnails not loading correct images when using code from "Another Advanced Pager Demo"

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using jQuery v1.5.1 and jQuery Cycle v2.99 with the code from this example page - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager3.html

You can see the site I'm working on here - http://bluehoop-demo.co.uk/accident/gallery

For some reason thumbnails 2,4 & 6 don't load any images.

Thumbnail 1 loads image 1

Thumbnail 3 loads image 2

Thumbnail 5 loads image 3

I've copied and pasted the exact code into a blank html template and it all works fine, so I'm assuming the problem is caused by Wordpress. I just haven't a clue how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress was automatically adding a break line after each of the larger images, this caused the script to hide/show the break lines instead of the images.

Removing these fixed the problem.